# Network Table assistance

Tags: networking, iptables, ip

I am designing a small network and have came up with the following table I am just wondering if this seems right, would appreciate some feedback, thanks.

```
Network/Router    First IP    Last IP   Subnet             Host         Broadcast

Router 1          162.10.0.1  162.10.0.7   255.255.255.248 162.10.0.0   162.10.0.8
Network 1         162.10.1.1  162.10.2.253 255.255.254.0   162.10.1.0   162.10.2.254
Network 2         162.10.0.9  162.10.0.14  255.255.255.248 162.10.0.8   162.10.0.15
Router 2          162.10.0.17 162.10.0.18  255.255.255.252 162.10.0.16  162.10.0.19
Network 3         162.10.0.21 162.10.0.146 255.255.255.128 162.10.0.20  162.10.0.147
```

Router one is the IP assigned by the ISP

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Answer (score 2):

```
Network/Router    First IP    Last IP   Subnet             Host         Broadcast
```

Change the host label to `Network` or network ID, that would be more accurate.  Calling those addresses a host address doesn't make any sense.  The Network ID, or Network Address, is the address within a subnet where all the host bits are zero.

```
Network 3         162.10.0.21 162.10.0.146 255.255.255.128 162.10.0.20  162.10.0.147
```

Sorry, but this one is wrong.  There is no way you can take a `/25` chunk out of the middle like that.  The arithmetic, simply doesn't work out that way.  If you need a `/25` you only have 2 choices.

```
162.10.0.1   162.10.0.126 255.255.255.128 162.10.0.0    162.10.0.127
162.10.0.129 162.10.0.254 255.255.255.128 162.10.0.128  162.10.0.255

Address:   162.10.0.0           10100010.00001010.00000000.0 0000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.128 = 25 11111111.11111111.11111111.1 0000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.127            00000000.00000000.00000000.0 1111111
Network:   162.10.0.0/25        10100010.00001010.00000000.0 0000000
HostMin:   162.10.0.1           10100010.00001010.00000000.0 0000001
HostMax:   162.10.0.126         10100010.00001010.00000000.0 1111110
Broadcast: 162.10.0.127         10100010.00001010.00000000.0 1111111

Address:   162.10.0.128         10100010.00001010.00000000.1 0000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.128 = 25 11111111.11111111.11111111.1 0000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.127            00000000.00000000.00000000.0 1111111
Network:   162.10.0.128/25      10100010.00001010.00000000.1 0000000
HostMin:   162.10.0.129         10100010.00001010.00000000.1 0000001
HostMax:   162.10.0.254         10100010.00001010.00000000.1 1111110
Broadcast: 162.10.0.255         10100010.00001010.00000000.1 1111111
```

---

```
Network 1         162.10.1.1  162.10.2.253 255.255.254.0   162.10.1.0   162.10.2.254
```

Sorry, this one won't work either.  A `/23` that included the address `162.10.1.1` would need to start at `162.10.0.1`, and go to `162.10.1.254`.  Like this.

```
Address:   162.10.0.0           10100010.00001010.0000000 0.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.254.0 = 23   11111111.11111111.1111111 0.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.1.255            00000000.00000000.0000000 1.11111111
=>
Network:   162.10.0.0/23        10100010.00001010.0000000 0.00000000
HostMin:   162.10.0.1           10100010.00001010.0000000 0.00000001
HostMax:   162.10.1.254         10100010.00001010.0000000 1.11111110
Broadcast: 162.10.1.255         10100010.00001010.0000000 1.11111111
```

So to summarize, you have a lot of impossible subnets on that table.  You need to take some time, and go back to the subletting fundamentals.

Comment: So if router 1 has the ip address 162.10.0.0, how can the network address of network 1 be the same?

Comment: I understand the network 3 problem as I would have to start with the largest first then break it down from there

Comment: @mitchnufc, not sure were you are seeing me suggest a router address of `162.10.0.0`.  That would not be a valid IP address that could be assigned to a host unless you had a mask between `/1` and `/14`.

Comment: SO i could use Router 1 address 162.10.0.0, then network 1 162.10.0.1/23 - 162.0.1.254/23 with the Host address 162.10.0.0 and the broadcast 162.10.0.2545

Comment: What do you think the word **host** means?  Calling `162.10.0.0` a host address doesn't make any sense.  A **host** is just a computer or a system.  A host address would be a valid IP that could be assigned to a computer.  As I mentioned `162.10.0.0` isn't a valid IP, unless you have a really large network, but what actually could be is a NETWORK ID, or Network address.  A network address the address where all the host bits are 0.

Comment: I mean't and I just had it in my head that the network address can't be the same as the router it feeds of like above.